# Why theoretical ACF in the not stationary case is not exist?

Tags: self-study, acf-pacf

My professor told us that ACF will not exist if the model is not stationary but leave us to figure out why.

Comment: Please put a self-study tag and read the [policy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) related to homework questions. A hint for the above question is that each $X_t$ in a time series is a different random variable. So correlation between $X_t, X_{t+\tau}$ should be a function of $t, \tau$. The way ACF is defined, this correlation should be independent of $t$. Under what conditions can that be true?

Comment: Your professor *must* mean some form of *weak* stationarity.  At https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/282875/919 I provided a counterexample to the statement you quote: namely, an example of a time series process that has an ACF but is not stationary.

Answer (score 0):

You can define auto-correlation functions for non-stationary time series.

- An auto-correlation like this

  $$\sum_{t=0}^n X_t \overline{X_{t+\tau}}$$

  can always be computed for a *sample*.
- Also a correlation function in terms of the *expectation* can always be expressed (except if the covariance or 2nd moment is not defined which may occur with distributions that have infinite or undefined higher moments)

  $$\varphi(t_1,t_2) = E[X_{t_1} \overline{X_{t_2}}]$$

  or expressed in terms of a time difference.

  $$\varphi(t,\tau) = E[X_t \overline{X_{t+\tau}}]$$

  For a non-stationary time series this type of correlation function in terms of the expectation will not only depend on the time difference $\tau$ but also on the time $t$.  It is gonna be dependent on both changes in the mean and/or variance and so this expectation is not constant for any point in time and varies with $t$,

However,

- The typical correlation function is only a function of the time difference

  $$\varphi(\tau) = E[X_t \overline{X_{t+\tau}}]$$

  For this to make sense and be well-defined, this requires $\varphi(t,\tau)$ to be dependent on $\tau$ only. That is, it needs to be independent of time

  $$\forall t: \varphi(t,\tau) = \varphi(\tau)$$

  For a non-stationary time series you do not have that : $\varphi(t,\tau)$ is constant in time $t$. Tondescribe the auto-correlation as a function of $\tau$ only would be ambiguous. Which time point are you gonna choose to define *the* ACF of the series?

But there is a middleway:

- If you standardise the auto-correlation function

  $$\frac{E[(X_t -\mu_t) \overline{(X_{t+\tau} -\mu_{t+\tau})}]}{\sigma_t \sigma_{t+\tau}}$$

  then for some non-stationary time series this type of auto-correlation function may still work. (And actually, also for the non-standardised auto-correlation function you can have that for some non-stationary sequences the auto-correlation is defined. As Whuber shower [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282635) by generating two distributions that are different, but still have equal covariance)

Comment: I think there is a failure of logic in this answer.  You correctly establish that the "ACF" must be a function of $(t,\tau)$ rather than $\tau$ alone: but that does not demonstrate the claim in the question.  Indeed, it looks perfectly possible that for some $\tau$ this expectation will not vary with $t,$ controverting your statements in the second bullet. What is needed is to analyze that possibility in the context of a clear definition of what you mean by "stationary."